# Encrypt user password android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, encryption

I am developing an android application , I use an Rest Api to send username and password in registration

Now the data and the passwords are saved as plan text in the database

What should I use or do the encrypt the data before sending it to the database ?

And what is the best way?

I am using java and phpmyadmin

Note:

I need to be able to decrypt the cypher text because if the user wants to sign in from different device

Comment: Jan's anwer explains the basics, what I would like to add is that you should always use one-way hashing on passwords, so they are not recoverable in case of a data breach, and you should always put the secure logic on the server, otherwise the hash essentially becomes the password itself, if it is being calculated client side.

Comment: I don't see how your note follows; if your users wish to sign in from a different device, just authenticate them again using the same process from the first device (hash the password they enter, using a salt value, and compare it to what's stored in the database). You shouldn't need to decrypt it in order to authenticate a second device.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So you're using MySQL as the database, you can simply let the database hash it for you in the SQL statement using the function you wish.

You'd want to have a 1-way hashing rather than 2-way encryption. With 1-way hash (the normal way to store passwords), you can sign-in from any device, and reset passwords (you cant recover the plaintext original).

Example 1-way:

Signup SQL:

```
INSERT INTO user_sha2 VALUES ('member1',SHA2('secretpassword',512) );
```

Login SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM user_sha2 WHERE user_name='member1' AND password=SHA2('secretpassword',512);
```

If a user needs to recover their password, you would usually just let them reset it by giving them a reset token and letting them pick a new password if the token matches.

If you want them to get their password back in plain text (**Please don't do this!**) then you need 2-way encryption like AES. See below:

Signup SQL:

```
INSERT INTO user_aes VALUES ('member1',AES_ENCRYPT('secretpassword','my_secret_key_to_encrypt') );
```

Login SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM user_aes WHERE user_name='member1' AND password=AES_ENCRYPT('secretpassword','my_secret_key_to_encrypt');
```

Recover SQL:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(password, 'my_secret_key_to_encrypt') AS unencrypted FROM user_aes ;
```

Source:
Check out this link for more info: http://mysqldatabaseadministration.blogspot.com/2006/08/storing-passwords-in-mysql.html

Comment: You should never encrypt passwords, only hash them.  You should never use a message digest (like SHA1) as a password hash.  Use Argon2, bcrypt, scrypt or PBKDF2.